# Android Firebase messaging, server side

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am quite new to Android development, and I am reading this guide on Firebase messaging: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#7 . 
I have two questions, one is technical and the other less so:

1. Where can I find a tutorial that describes how to set up a server (preferably Node or Python) to handle messages sent from devices? Specifically, what do I do to (1) read messages sent by a client, (2) modify them in a certain way, (3) push modified messages to a filtered group of users.
2. What is a standard way to handle messages in the database? Do apps normally delete them, encrypt them or just let them stay in the database using default settings, just like in the tutorial?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ad 1) one example https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html, 2) there is no standard way, it all depends on your use-case.

Comment: Found the tutorial I have been looking for https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio